The roles of convection and advection in the absolute flux for species $i$ in mass transfer
I am confused as I have been reading on mass transport on multiple sources and they seem to use "advection" and "convection" interchangeably in the equation for the absolute flux of a species:
$$\vec{n}_i = \vec{j}_i +\rho\vec{v}$$
All references I have come across refer to $\vec{j}$ as the diffusion transport component, but some refer to $\rho\vec{v}$ as convection while others refer to it as advection.
Which description is right, as far as I had understood convection and advection were not the same? Based on other questions in this stack I understood that convection = diffusion + advection.
Similarly, the component of the material derivative for some property $P$ associated with the velocity field of the flow $(\vec{v} \cdot \nabla)P$, is called "convective acceleration", but this is often the transport of some property $P$ due to the bulk motion of the flow (which is what I understand as advection).
